# How can i get to match the pattern as follows using (?:regex) in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
$string = "hello/welcome";
```

i want "welcome" only.

```
$string = "hello-welcome-to-the-world";
```

i want "hello-welcome"

i try this

```
print $1 if($string =~ m#(?:/|)(.*)(?:-to-)#);  # got hello-welcome
print $1 if($string =~ m#(?:/)(.*)(?:-to-|)#);  # got welcome
```

but i cant able to get the required output from single regexp  .
please solve and explain ...

by using this `(?:\w.+/)?(.*?(?=$|-to-))` , i got the answer for both strings

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? Maybe show what you're getting for output compared to your expected output.

Comment: If the question is resolved, please either accept an answer, or post an answer of how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches both of your cases. The desired output is also in `$1`.

```
((?:\w+-)?welcome)
```

The `(?:\w+-)?` optionally matches a word then hyphen preceding welcome. Since it matches optionally, if it isn't there, output is just "welcome".

Comment: looks good , i got the output. 
is any possible to match these without match "welcome" ?
like, after the final slash and "-to" .
thanks

Comment: thanks kevlar, i got the answer from your logic

i changed little bit to " (?:\w.+/)?(.*?(?=$|-to-)) "

Comment: if this has answered your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=^|/).*?(?=$|-to-)
```

This matches the shortest match between (start of string or slash) and (end of string or -to-).

This is another one of those many cases where extracting capturing groups isn't necessary, if you use lookaround.

Edit: Since variable-length lookbehind doesn't work, try this:

```
(?<![^/])[^/]*?(?=$|-to-)
```

Comment: thanks frey .
i got error "Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/((?<=^|/).*?(?=$|-to-))/" for matching those strings.

Comment: I edited the question and added another version of the regex.

Comment: sorry frey , 2nd string returns correctly but 1st string doesn't return any value.
i'm try this and get both values " (?:\w.+/)?(.*?(?=$|-to-)) "

thanks frey.

Comment: I edited the question again. I think the new regex will work.